# Auto-rounding up problems python

Tags: python-2.7, hex, rounding, fractions

I am working on a problem, that essentially it comes down to solving the following equation (b/n)*((b-1)/(n-1)) = 0.5, where only the lower limit of n is 10**12. I was able to solve the problem making use of methods described here https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM

However I also tried solving the problem as a quadratic equation, and checking than the answers are integers, and that the required ratio is reached. The program works for lower values of n, but as soon it starts approaching the required limit (10**12), it starts giving false solutions. For example, the program yields 
b = 707106783028 and
n = 1000000002604
as a set of solutions, and yet it is not -> (b/n)*((b-1)/(n-1)) gives 0.499999999999, however python just takes it as 0.5. I tried using x.hex() to try to account for that, but it did not help. Is there any way to make python store/display the true (or most accurate) value of a float?

Comment: Use `repr()` to convert your float to string.  With `repr()`  "[Python displays a value](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) based on the shortest decimal fraction that rounds correctly back to the true binary value."  The problem your running into is that your relying on Python 2.7's default string representation of floats which rounded the value.  This was fixed in Python 3 but could not be changed in Python 2 because it would break existing programs.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it only delays occurrence of a false value for a while. Now according to python n =707106802629 and i = 1000000030324 are a set of solutions. The equation yields 0.5 even on an online scientific calculator, yet according to the correct solution that is not the case. Perhaps due to the way calculators work, solving such problem using quadratic equation is impossible?

Comment: Okay.  Looking at your problem you don't need floats at all (which will often be imprecise).  This equation `(b/n)*((b-1)/(n-1)) = 0.5` says that when you multiply two fractions the resulting fraction will be have a numerator that is half the size of the denominator.  You could test that with an if-statement `if 2*b*(b-1) == n*(n-1):` which will give you a simple `True` or `False`.

Comment: You could also use some mathematics: you can obtain solutions to your equality from solutions of [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) with `n=2`.